# How to write jQuery dropdown menus

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of drop drown menus to work with on my page and I need some help understanding what I need to do to get things to work the way I want them to. The first menu I have is named: Product. The Product menu has 3 options: Sports, Transportation, & School. Each of those 3 options have their own drop menu I want to have show up next to the Product menu as someone selects them. I was told to use the fallowing code, but I don't know how to use it, and can't find anything to explain it well to me.

```
    $('#Select').change(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == '1') {
           $('#select').css({'display':'block'});           
       }
    });
```

I would like to take this two more steps now. My Sports menu has 5 options to pick from: Baseball, Basketball, Football, Soccer, & Racing. How would I write this to show the individual sports menus next to the Sports menu?

The other step I want to take this:

My racing menu has 3 options: Racing1, Racing2, & Racing3. How would I write the code to show a picture of what each of them are as someone selects them?

Would you please explain the code to me as you write the answer, as I have a lot more menu to do this with, and I want to understand how to do this, so I can do it with every menu I have.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you post more code please? We will need your HTML to see exactly what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question directly, but I see this as my duty to suggest this to you.

Instead of **reinventing the wheel** why not use what is already built for you, and is opensource, free and heavily tested on different browsers/platforms.

So I begin with Bootstrap Framework, If you are already using bootstrap then its pretty easy to implement a menu using the menu module.

If you want a standalone solution there are like thousands of [options with CSS3 + jQuery combination](https://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-css3-menu).

and If you still want to write the menu from scratch then [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412650/drop-down-menu-jquery-css) may be of some interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

K so assuming you have [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) included in your project, doing something like you want works like this.

First create your markup (HTML):

```
    <div class="page-container">

        <div class="selectors-container">
            <div class="selector" data-select="product">Products</div>
            <div class="selector" data-select="sports">Sports</div>
            <div class="selector" data-select="school">School</div>
        </div>

        <div class="select-menus">
            <select id="products"><define options here></select>
            <select id="sports"><define options here></select>
            <select id="school"><define options here></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note that `id` attributes of the selects are equal to the `data-select` attribute of the root items.

Now create some `CSS` to hide the selects at the start, and format them as you specified as well:

```
.selectors-container {
    float:left; //floats make things stack on eachother horizontally.
}
.select-menus select {
    display:none; //elements with display:none are invisible.
    float:left; //floats make things stack on eachother horizontally
}
.select-menus select.active {
    display:block; //we want to show a select when it has the class 'active' 
}
```

Now script some `jQuery` to make everything work nicely.

```
$(".selector").mouseenter(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //makes sure nothing happens that usually does when this event is triggered (redundant here).
    var selectId = $(this).data('select'); //access the element we're hovering by using the `this` keyword, it accesses the element that is triggering the event.
    $(".select-menus select").removeClass("active"); //hide all selects again
    $("#"+selectId).addClass("active"); //show the select that we're hovering.
});
```

Now this should do as you please, Im sure I forgot some details here and there, but you should be able to figure those out Im sure, Google is your friend.